# accessing sysdata.rda within package functions

Tags: r, r-package

I thought that putting an internal dataset for a package into `R/sysdata.rda` would make the data accessible to my functions.  But I can't seem to figure out how to actually access this dataframe.  None of the [documentation](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html) actually says how to access the data, but my guess was that I could simply refer to the dataframe by name.  However, this does not seem to work.

I used `devtools::use_data()` with `internal = TRUE` and sysdata.rda was created.  Lazy-loading is set to TRUE.

To test it, I manually loaded it just to make sure it was the right file.  The file is called `nhanes_files`.  Within my function, I simply refer to the `nhanes_files` object and extract the necessary data.  When I tested my function in my package project, it seemed to work.  When I build and load the package, upload to GitHub, and then install the package into a new project, I get an error:  `Error in find_data() : object 'nhanes_files' not found`

Do I need to do something else to make this internal data accessible to my functions?

Below is the most basic function, which is not working:

```
#' Print NHANES file listing
#'
#' Provides access to the internal data listing all NHANES files
#'
#' @return A data frame with the list of files that can be accessed through the NHANES website.  Should not generally be used.  Present for debugging purposes and transparency.
#' @export
find_data <- function(){
    nhanes_files
}
```

Comment: Have a look at http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html for r package development. That should help

Comment: That is where I started.  It doesn't actually answer this question.  I linked to this resource above already.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I missed that, sorry.

Comment: It was a GitHub error on my part.  For the record, one simply has to refer to the file as above and it all works.

Comment: I had a similar problem where I'd saved the file as sysdata.Rda instead of sysdata.rda. Case matters. See stackoverflow.com/a/62418855/4241780

Answer (score 16):

If your package name is `somepackage` and the object saved was `nhanes_files` with `devtools::use_data(nhanes_files, internal = TRUE)` then you can access this in your functions by calling `somepackage:::nhanes_files`.
Pay attention, there're 3 `:` here.

Answer (score 5):

I use `myobject <- get0("myobject", envir = asNamespace("mypackage"))`.

This formulation passes `R CMD CHECK`. It is possible to change the name of the value, and it works to access objects in other loaded packages.